# if 'x evaluates to (var x) in clojure, why aren't they equal?

Tags: clojure

In the O'Reilly "Clojure Programming: Practical Lisp for the Java World", there is a statement:

> The var special form does this:

```
(def x 5)
(var x) 
;= #' user/x
```

> You’ve seen a number of times now how vars are printed in the REPL: #', followed by a symbol. This is reader syntax that expands to a call to var:

```
 #'x 
 ;= #' user/x
```

> (Kindle Locations 1278-1282).

Testing this out doesn't seem to be the case.   I would think the type types would be the same.

```
[user]> (def x 5)
#'user/x

[user]> (= 'x (var x))
false

[user]> (type 'x)
#<Class@c540f5a clojure.lang.Symbol>

[user]> (type (var x))
#<Class@77e9807f clojure.lang.Var>

[user]> 'x
x

[user]> (var x)
#'user/x
```

Comment: `'x` evaluates to `(quote x)`, not `(var x)`. `(= 'x (quote x))` evaluates to `true`. `x` is simply a symbol. It need not refer to a `var`, or anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `#` symbol:

```
(def x 5)
(spyx (var x))
(spyx #'x)

(var x) => #'tst.clj.core/x
(var x) => #'tst.clj.core/x
```

The clojure reader consumes the charcters in your source file, and does a substitution of `#'x` => `(var x)` before it even gets to the compiler.  As you can see above, the `spyx` macro ("spy expression") doesn't even see the original `#'x` expression - the substitution has already occurred.

Thus we get:

```
(= #'x (var x)) => true
```

You can also try:

```
(println "type 1:  " (type (var x)))
(println "type 2:  " (type #'x))

;=> type 1:   clojure.lang.Var
;=> type 2:   clojure.lang.Var
```

If you wish to play with the `spy`, `spyx`, or `spyxx` macros, you will need to add this to your `project.clj`:

```
   [tupelo "0.9.19"]
```

Comment: You can demonstrate the read-time replacement even more clearly by examining the results of simply quoting the inputs: `'[(var x) #'x]`.

Comment: ah, thanks.   you know, I think I got confused and thought the `#` was a prompt.